# Alternative to Dictionary for doing fast key lookups?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, data-structures

I run into situations where I need to keep track if I've processed a particular value. In these cases, I use `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` to keep track of the values that I've processed. Basically, as each value is processed, I insert the processed value into as key into the dictionary. When I want to see if I've processed that value, I use the `ContainsKey` method to see if the value exists in the collection.

This works well, but I do have to insert something in the value side of the key-value pair. I would just use a `List(Of T)` but I want the performance of the hash table lookup that Dictionary provides. Is there a data collection in .Net that is more suitable for this purpose?

Comment: Is there a secondary key that `TValue` has which you can use?  If not, the best you can do is a `List<T>` and lookup using a predicate.

Comment: @casperOne: No, I just need the key.

Comment: If you are already keying on one property, but don't have a second property to distinguish items in a group (you're really doing a `group by` here) then no dictionary is going to help you.

Comment: @casperOne: I'm must have misunderstood what you were asking. The Dictionary if helpful to me in that it provides a way to store and quickly check a set of unique keys. Its just annoying to have to put something in the value side of the pair.

Comment: Got it.  [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would suggest a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). You could just enter the key, if all you need to know is that the key has already been used.

It's really simple, too:

```
if (myHashSet.Add(key))
{
    // item wasn't in the hash set, so process it.
}
```

`Add` is like "add if not there." It returns `true` if the item was added. It returns `false` if the item was already in the collection.

Or, you can use `Contains` to test, and then `Add` to add.

Comment: This is why I love this site: I did not realize HashSet even existed prior to this answer (I have been programming in .Net since 1.0, so sometimes new things sneak by). Now that I do, I have a much better way to solve a number of problems. Thanks!

Comment: @competent_tech and if you decompile them, you'll see that HashSet uses the same implementation as dictionary's key collection.

Answer (score 3):

On .NET 3.5 or later, you can use a `HashSet` for that purpose. The methods you need are called `Add` and `Contains`. Both operations have time complexity O(log *n*), as opposed to O(*n*) for a `List`.

Comment: Actually, `Add` and `Contains` are O(1). See the documentation.

Comment: @Jim Huh? Can't seem to find that.

Comment: In remarks here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx . "If Count is less than the capacity of the internal array, this method is an O(1) operation. If the HashSet<T> object must be resized, this method becomes an O(n) operation, where n is Count."

Comment: Thanks! I realize I'm really getting tired. Now it looks like O(1) and O(*n*) are best case and worst case time complexity respectively, which is the same as for a List (!). The _average_ time complexity for a HashSet lookup is O(log *n*), which is better than the average lookup time complexity for a List, O(*n*).

Comment: The average time complexity for a `HashSet<T>` *lookup* is O(1). The only time O(n) enters the picture is when the collection has to be resized during an Add operation, and you can eliminate that by pre-allocating it. See http://blog.mischel.com/2008/05/21/more-on-net-collection-sizes/

Comment: Not quite. A HashSet can store different elements in the same bucket. If a bucket contains more elements, all of them must be compared with the element being added or searched for to ensure the new element is not already in the set. Preallocating memory won't prevent objects to share the same bucket. The worst case is of course, when all objects happen to have the same hash code, in which case they will all share the same bucket, and that's definitely O(*n*).

Comment: @ft1 worst case is O(n), true, but amortized average time complexity is O(1), *assuming a well-designed hash function*.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use [System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.aspx), but I am not sure it is as performant as Dictionary and requires you to cast keys to strings.

If the requirement to always include something in the Add method is annoying, you could create your own generic keys class, which could be adapted to better underlying .Net implementations as they are found. For example, assuming VB.Net:

```
Public Class KeyDictionary(Of T)
    Inherits Dictionary(Of T, Boolean)

    Public Overloads Sub Add(key As T)
        MyBase.Add(key, False)
    End Sub
End Class
```

then to declare an instance and add a value:

```
    Dim cKeys As New KeyDictionary(Of Integer)

    If Not cKeys.ContainsKey(1) Then
        cKeys.Add(1)
    End If
```

And, in C#:

```
public class KeyDictionary<T> : Dictionary<T, bool>
{
    public void Add(T key)
    {
        base.Add(key, false);
    }
}
```

to declare an instance and add a value:

```
        var cKeys = new KeyDictionary<int>();

        if (!(cKeys.ContainsKey(1)))
        {
            cKeys.Add(1);
        }
```